# How to link two components with html/components inbetween with React.js

Tags: reactjs

As a general question, how would I separate two connected components?  For example, if I had a layout:

```
section 1
     some list (component 1)

assorted html elements

other components

etc...

section 2
     output from list clicking (component 2)
```

In this instance, do I include the other html/components within component 1?  Or is there a way to have the list and the output appear in different sections of the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a 3rd parent component as a container around the inner two components. Have component 1 have a property which is a callback function, and have component 1 call that callback with the data needed by the second component when the click event is fired. The parent component can then pass this data on as props. For example:

```
function Component1(props) {
  var onClick = function(e) {
    props.callback(e, "hello");
  };
  return (
    <ul>
      <li onClick={onClick}>Some content</li>
    </ul>
  );
}

function Component2(props) {
  return (
    <p>{props.text}</p>
  );
}

var parentComponent = React.createClass({
  onComponent1Click: function(e, val) {
    this.setState({ text: val });
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <section>
          <Component1 callback={this.onComponent1Click} />
        </section>
        <p>Some other HTML</p>
        <section>
          <Component2 text={this.state.text} />
        </section>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: but in this case, the components are still right next to each other are they not?

Comment: @user1072337 Hi, sorry for not coming back and updating this. Assuming you've gotten it at this point, but I've gone ahead and updated my answer just to make sure its clear. :)